# Return negative in Unix Shell Script Functions

Tags: shell, unix

in a script, I am returning negative integer from a function. I one envrionment with Bash Version : GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) the script is running

and in other envrionment with Bash Version : GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) the script is not running and it terminates as soon as it gets return -1008 in a function.
when I am trying to return positive integer instead of negative, its working fine.

I am not sure whether this is because the bash version difference. but what could be the issue ?

return -1008

Comment: What error message does it dump before terminating?

Comment: The `return` statement is meant for status codes, not arbitrary data. A shell function isn't a function in the usual sense; it communicates with its caller via a file descriptor (i.e., writing to standard output or some other file) or by setting a global variable.

Comment: this is the final error message : + return -1008
loadDecisionMetricData.bsh: line 165: return: -1: invalid option

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and also copy-paste the full and complete output of that minimal example. And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: calling the below function like this : exists_hdfs_folder $daily_originaldata_folder
this is : 
function exists_hdfs_folder(){
 local folder=$1
 info "Checking if \"${folder}\" exists in hdfs.... "
 hadoop fs -test -d $folder

 if  [ "$?" -eq "$OK"  ]; then
  info "HDFS FOLDER EXISTS - folder:${folder}"
  return $OK
 else
  info "HDFS FOLDER DOES NOT EXIST - folder:${folder}"
  return $ERROR_GENERIC_HDFS_FOLDER_NOT_EXISTS
 fi
}

Comment: And use the **`edit`** link to edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Return values are generally modulo 256:

```
#!/bin/sh
foo() { printf "Return $1: "; return $1; }

foo -5; echo $?
foo 300; echo $?
$ ./a.sh
Return -5: 251
Return 300: 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a value with an echo when you don't write other things to stdout:

```
exists_hdfs_folder()
{
   local folder=$1
   # info "Checking if \"${folder}\" exists in hdfs.... "
   hadoop fs -test -d $folder 2>&1 > /dev/null
   if [ "$?" -eq "$OK" ]; then 
      # info "HDFS FOLDER EXISTS - folder:${folder}"
      echo "$OK"
   else
      # info "HDFS FOLDER DOES NOT EXIST - folder:${folder}"
      echo "$ERROR_GENERIC_HDFS_FOLDER_NOT_EXISTS"
      # offtopic: Better lowercase and braces like
      # echo "${error_generic_hdfs_folder_not_exists}"
   fi 
}
```

And call that function with

```
returnvalue=$(exists_hdfs_folder)
```

I commented the `info` function, it might write to stdout.
When you do want functions writing to stdout, you might use a variable

```
exists_hdfs_folder()
{
   local folder=$1
   # global
   retval_exists_hdfs_folder="-99"

   info "Checking if \"${folder}\" exists in hdfs.... "
   hadoop fs -test -d $folder 2>&1 > /dev/null
   if [ "$?" -eq "$OK" ]; then 
      info "HDFS FOLDER EXISTS - folder:${folder}"
      retval_exists_hdfs_folder="$OK"
      return 0
   else
      info "HDFS FOLDER DOES NOT EXIST - folder:${folder}"
      retval_exists_hdfs_folder="${error_generic_hdfs_folder_not_exists}"
      return 1
   fi 
}
```

And call that function with

```
exists_hdfs_folder || { echo "Failure: ${retval_exists_hdfs_folder}"; }
```